# pytest cant import modules and gives SyntaxError

Tags: python, syntax-error, pytest, importerror

I am using pytest to test my functions in a directory that looks like this:

```
├── my_dir
    ├── Sam_Functions
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── AD.py                 
        ├── Pr.py
    ├── Test_Functions
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── test_AD.py
        ├── test_Pr.py
```

AD.py and Pr.py work fine with no issues. However, in pytest I face these errors:

- AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'choices'
- AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Seaborn'
- SyntaxError: invalid syntax for *_ when I want to ignore last few outputs of AD.py

Any idea how I can resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to add path address into ur testing case.
You can add one more file and add path of dir and then call both test case into same. So thet u need not to add file again and again.
For debugging u can use print command and run this python test casees with specific options.

Secondly ut creating lib why r u not testing completely out of mydir folder.

Comment: I think I am doing what you are suggesting here. I point out to the Test_Function path and then run pytest from terminal. Do you think running from terminal is an issue? I forgot to mention I am in vm

Comment: I am going to accept this answer as it eventually worked for me. For whatever reason, running pytest from terminal was an issue. I got many errors with imports and syntax. However, calling and running test functions from a new file resolved the issue. I believe there is an incompatibility issue between pytest version and python version on linux platform where I am running codes.

Answer (score 0):

try importing the other path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/my_dir/Test Functions")
```

or you can do it from the shell with:

```
setenv PATH $PATH:"my_dir/Test Functions"
```

Comment: I added the code to my test_Pr.py and still dsnt find Seaborn. I point out to the directory in terminal when I want to run pytest so I think I am already doing what you have suggested but in a different way.

Comment: Please share the segment of your code that includes files and a ls or dir of your directory structure.